# Why can Random Cut Forest's `record_set()` method for data conversion/upload not be used with the "test" channel?

Tags: boto3, random-forest, amazon-sagemaker

## Original Question

I want to use RCF's "test" channel, to get performance-metrics of the model.

I have previously used the [`record_set()`](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/algorithms/randomcutforest.html?highlight=record_set#sagemaker.RandomCutForest.record_set) method without specifying a channel and training worked fine.

However if I upload my feature matrix and label vector using `record_set()` and set `channel='test'` like this:

```py
from sagemaker import RandomCutForest

rcf = RandomCutForest(
    role=execution_role,
    instance_count=1,
    instance_type='ml.m5.large',
    data_location=f's3://{bucket}/{prefix}/',
    output_path=f's3://{bucket}/{prefix}/output',
    base_job_name=base_job_name,
    eval_metrics=['accuracy', 'precision_recall_fscore']
)

test_set = rcf.record_set(
    features,
    labels=labels,
    channel='test'
)

rcf.fit(test_set)
```

... I get the following error during training:

> Failure reason
> ClientError: Unable to initialize the algorithm. Failed to validate input data configuration. (caused by ValidationError) Caused by: 'ShardedByS3Key' is not one of ['FullyReplicated'] Failed validating 'enum' in schema['properties']['test']['properties']['S3DistributionType']: {'enum': ['FullyReplicated'], 'type': 'string'} On instance['test']['S3DistributionType']: 'ShardedByS3Key'

---

### Appendix

The same is true for HPO-jobs that use data on the "test" channel:

```py
from sagemaker.tuner import HyperparameterTuner, IntegerParameter

hpo = HyperparameterTuner(
    estimator=rcf,
    objective_metric_name='test:f1',
    hyperparameter_ranges={
        'num_samples_per_tree': IntegerParameter(32, 512),
        'num_trees': IntegerParameter(50, 1000)
    },
    max_jobs=10,
    max_parallel_jobs=2
)

train_set = rcf.record_set(
    features,
    channel='train'
)

test_set = rcf.record_set(
    features,
    labels=labels,
    channel='test'
)

hpo.fit([train_set, test_set])
```

Again the initial upload and "train" channel work fine, the "test" channel fails:

[image]

---

#### EDIT 1

I tried to instantiate my own `RecordSet` objects like this (after the data was already uploaded to S3 in the correct format):

```py
train_data = RecordSet(
    s3_data='s3://path-to-train-data/.amazon.manifest',
    feature_dim=features.shape[1],
    num_records=features.shape[0],
    s3_data_type='ManifestFile',
    channel='train'
)

test_data = RecordSet(
    s3_data='s3://path-to-test-data/.amazon.manifest',
    feature_dim=features.shape[1],
    num_records=features.shape[0],
    s3_data_type='ManifestFile',
    channel='test'
)
```

But the same error occurs. The issue is, that the constructor of `RecordSet` does not permit to pass a different `distribution` argument. It is hardcoded to be `ShardedByS3Key`, as can be seen in the source code [HERE](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/2ebba8a454de03a2bc49267c91dbacddd6183585/src/sagemaker/amazon/amazon_estimator.py#L340).

I've also opened an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/issues/2925), since this bug is still present in the latest version of SageMaker.

#### EDIT 2

There is another post on a similar issue on StackOverflow, where an older version of the Python API is used: [Sagemaker Random Cut Forest Training with Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68161725/sagemaker-random-cut-forest-training-with-validation).

After some refactoring in newer versions, users don't have to create `TrainingInput` objects anymore. This is now supposed to be done via `record_set()` (which returns the class `RecordSet`). As a result, we lose control over the `distribution` property of the underlying `TrainingInput` object and can't set it to `FullyReplicated` anymore.

This is essentially what breaks the "test" channel for RCF in current versions of SageMaker and also prevents hyperparameter optimization via `HyperparameterTuner`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for opening the issue, I added a +1.
In the meantime, you can use alternative SDKs to train Random Cut Forest and set test channel distribution to FullyReplicated.

For example, those SDKs should give you this control:

- AWS CLI [create_training_job](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sagemaker/create-training-job.html)
- [boto3 create_training_job](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html#SageMaker.Client.create_training_job)
- SageMaker Python SDK [Estimator](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/estimators.html#) to which you pass the RCF docker image in `image_uri` parameter

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I went with the 3rd option in the meantime, after I found some examples and explored the docs.